# Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 - mild confusion

Tags: android, android-layout

According to [this guide's chapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview) `px = dp * (dpi / 160)` and to [that](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) layout specifications change from buckets(physical size in inches) to "dp" units so that:

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
  hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Since "dp" values depend on "px" and "dpi" values so that: `dp = px / (dpi / 160)` - isn't it possible that a phone device with high resolution will take a layout from w600dp folder?

For instance: Samsung galaxy s3 dp = 1280 / (303 / 160) = 670; Samsung galaxy s2 dp = 800 / (217 / 160) = 592. So, galaxy s3 is going to take "tablet-oriented" template, right. Is it okay, especially if a tablet version contains more elements and overall interface ergonomics gonna suffer from the tablet layout in case of s3 ? Why don't just stick to display buckets ?

You're probably going to recommend using "sw" key but I just want make sure that those "dp" units actually relate to sizes so that tablet-oriented template won't be shown on phone devices.

So, would you mind sharing your practical knowledge on applying the new approach ?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot that the 160dpi (=mdpi) are not a fixed value http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Answer (score 1):

A `dp` or `dip` is a (screen) Density Independant Pixel. The confusing part about that is that is mentions *pixel*. It is actually a unit similar to a centimeter or inch.

Each device defines a dpi bucket for it's screen, for example `mdpi` which is 160dpi. That means that you find 160 pixel across one inch on the screen. It's not 100% accurate since physical screens are usually not exactly 160 dpi (or whatever value that is defined for the bucket). But it's a value that comes close.

That means that 160dp on a perfect 160dpi screen are actually 160 pixel. On a device with a perfect xhdpi (=320dpi) screen those 160dp would be 320 pixel. (`px = 160dp * (320dpi / 160)`)

To work with `dp` don't think in pixel. Think in inch, milimeter or what unit you prefer. The recommended [48dp rythm](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#48dp-rhythm) for UI elements for example explains that

> On average, 48dp translate to a physical size of about 9mm (with some variability)

To approximate that: 50dp = one finger wide.

That hopefully explains why a typical 320dp phone screen is always smaller than a 720dp tablet screen although the smaller screen can have more pixel than the larger. The dpi / pixel thing is already factored into dp.

---

How to do different layout for different screensizes? (i.e. phone vs table)

Use the [screen size buckets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) (`small`, ..., `xlarge`) for the layout. They represent physical small to large screens. You don't need `sw600dp` etc unless you need to adjust very special cases.

The different dpi buckets should only concern you for images. E.g. high resolution images for high resolution screens *of any size* in the `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The S3 does not have a density of 160.

Comment: yep, it's 303 - you overlooked the value